# Auto-escape special characters in vimscript

Tags: python, vim

I am trying to put a string into the unnamed register with python:

```
python <<EOF
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import vim

def passStrNc(myString):
    cmd = """let @" = "{0}" """.format(myString)
    vim.command(cmd)

EOF
```

Normally it works, but not when the string contains a double quote. Is there a way to auto-escape it?
I am also worried that the string may contain other special characters that may mess things up, is there a way to escape all of them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Vim's single quotes is recommended, because then, only the single quotes themselves need to be doubled:

```
cmd = """let @" = '%s'""" % str(myString).replace("'", "''")
```